# Want to redirect intranet based on AD group membership

Tags: intranet

I want one intranet address, www.myintranet.com to be used for every member in the company.  There are two main groups, employees and contractors.  I want to use the same IP address and the same name, but I want to redirect it to a different page based on AD group membership.  IIS is the platform.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?  It's best to do this in your application logic.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably be better off doing this in your application code.  Enable Integrated Windows Authentication to your application, which will allow your code to get the logon user.

Then, in code, you will need to check if that logon user is a member of a group that you care about; if so you will want to redirect to that group's folder, if not you will want to show a generic page.

If your intranet app is built in ASP.NET, you should be able to get the user's groups from the `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups` collection and perform the redirect with `Response.Redirect("path/to/folder");`.

There may be a third-party `HttpModule` that you could install into IIS to do this for you (so you wouldn't have to write the code yourself) but I've not worked with any.